# Procedure select nothing in result

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My procedure in mysql is follows:

```
delimiter //
create procedure getLineStasticFreightList(in start int(4),in row int(4),in stationIDD varchar(4),in dateStart datetime,in dateEnd datetime)
BEGIN
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS rqusg_lineStasticFreightUser;
CREATE VIEW rqusg_lineStasticFreightUser AS 
SELECT a.id, c.stationName as station,b.name as track,sum(a.dddwTime) AS zgdddwsj, sum(a.ddzxTime) AS zgddzxsj, sum(a.zxzyTime) AS zgzxzysj, sum(a.ddzngyTime) AS zgddzngysj, sum(a.hcddqsTime) AS zgddqssj
FROM rqusg_line_yard a
 join rqusg_line_tracks b
   on a.track = b.id
 join rqusg_line_stations c
   on a.stationID =  c.stationID
WHERE a.stationID = 'stationIDD' and a.arriveTime >= 'dateStart'  and a.clczTime <= 'dateEnd'
group by a.track
union
select a.id,c.stationName as station,b.name as track,sum(a.dddwTime) as zgdddwsj,sum(a.ddzxTime) as zgddzxsj,sum(a.zxzyTime) as zgzxzysj,sum(a.ddzngyTime) as zgddzngysj,sum(a.hcddqsTime) as zgddqssj
from rqusg_line_yard a
 join rqusg_line_tracks b
   on a.track = b.id
 join rqusg_line_stations c
   on a.stationID =  c.stationID
WHERE a.stationID = 'stationIDD' and a.arriveTime >= 'dateStart' and a.clczTime <= 'dateEnd'
group by a.track;
select * from rqusg_lineStasticFreightUser LIMIT start,row;
END
//
```

my procedure is to create a view and select all the deatails from the view,is there something wrong in the procedure?

Comment: All your procedure does is create a view, it doesn't select or return anything.

Comment: Is that the whole procedure? Where is the `END` statement?

Comment: Try removing `DROP VIEW IF EXISTS rqusg_lineStasticFreightUser;
CREATE VIEW rqusg_lineStasticFreightUser AS`, and adding an END after the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: sorry,My whole procedure is follows: